# Who will dispose of a computed created on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm building a SPA using knockout.js. In my viewmodels I often use the "on-the-fly" computeds trick to track changes and maintain state. Here is an example:

```
var fileBrowserViewModel = function() {
  this.currentFolder = ko.observable("/");
  this.folderPath = ko.observableArray(["/"]);

  // on-the-fly created computed to maintain folderpath when currentFolder changes
  ko.computed(function() {
    var index = this.folderPath.indexOf(this.currentFolder());
    if (index < 0)
      this.folderPath.push(this.currentFolder());
    else
      this.folderPath.splice(index+1, this.folderPath().length-index);
  }, this);     
}
```

I have a logic which disposes every publicly exposed computed property of the viewmodel. But what happens with these implicitly declared computeds after the wrapping viewmodel has been released?
How and when exactly are computeds disposed of? Could it cause memory leaks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout ViewModel computed garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730292/knockout-viewmodel-computed-garbage-collection)

Comment: You may be interested in [pure compute observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html). Before these were added to knockout, I implemented a different automatic computed-observable-cleaner at my job, but I recommend sticking with a built-in solution instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How and when exactly are computeds disposed of?**

They aren't, in the sense that, their `.dispose` functions are never called.

**Could it cause memory leaks?**

Maybe, but it won't always.  The reason computed's need to be `.dispose`'d, is because they subscriptions on their dependencies; which means that each dependency is holding a reference to the computed.  The computed will get garbage collected when there are no longer any references to it.  In the above example, that will happen when the ViewModel itself is no longer referenced anywhere, so the computed will get garbage collected along with its ViewModel, as intended.

However, if the computed depends on anything outside of the ViewModel that contains it, it will not get garbage collected until all of the things it depends on are themselves ready to be garbage collected.  In the worst case, where the computed depends on something global that is never garbage collected, the computed itself will never be garbage collected.

So, the real answer is that you only **need** to dispose a computed when it has dependencies that will be longer-lived than the computed itself.  However, as there's no harm to disposing a computed that would get garbage collected anyways, it's often just easier to make sure all computeds created by ViewModels get disposed; rather than trying to split hairs over which ones **need** to be disposed.

**How to handle computed disposal**

In any case, you'll want to have a `.dispose` method on your viewModel or some equivalent.  There's no way some external logic is going to be able to know about the privately created computeds, so the ViewModel itself will need to handle it itself.  The simple way to handle this is just to call `.dispose` on each privately created computed in the VM's `.dispose` method:

```
var fileBrowserViewModel = function() {
    // on-the-fly created computed to maintain folderpath when currentFolder changes
    var folderPathComputed = ko.computed(function() {
        //implementation omitted
    }, this);     

    this.dispose = function () {
        folderPathComputed.dispose();
    }
}
```

If you want something less manual; you can create a utility to handle the disposal for you e.g.:

```
function ComputedManager() {
    var computedsToDispose = [];

    this.computed = function() {
        //create a computed normally, with the provided arguments
        var computed = ko.computed.apply(ko, arguments);
        computedsToDispose.push(computed);
        return computed;
    }

    this.dispose = function() {
        computedsToDispose.forEach(function(computed) {
            computed.dispose();
        });
    }
}

var fileBrowserViewModel = function() {
    var computedManager = new ComputedManager();

    // on-the-fly created computed to maintain folderpath when currentFolder changes
    computedManager.computed(function() {
        //implementation omitted
    }, this);     

    this.dispose = computedManager.dispose;
}
```

It's a bit awkward to call `computedManager.computed` instead of `ko.computed` all the time, but it's easier than manually cleaning up every computed, and a benefit is that you could create all computeds this way, and then eliminate the need for some other logic to go through and find and dispose all publically exposed computeds.

Comment: Thank you for the really detailed and clean answer, I appreciate it. I have a base class (I'm using TypeScript) for all of my viewmodels, which has a dispose method, which iterates through public computed properties and calls "dispose". I like your second (automatic) approach, I will implement the overridden "computed" function in this base viewmodel class so I will need to use "this.computed" instead of "ko.computed" which is a bit more straightforward IMHO. This way the base "dispose" method will be cleaner as well.